# Can a sound like a sonic boom change a object like a wall? And how the light on the walls will be changed after a sound like this?

Tags: acoustics, material-science

Can a sound like a sonic boom change a object like a wall? And how the light on the walls will be changed after a sound like this? .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound, even very intense sound, is just a pressure wave. I'm guessing your *sonic bomb* is producing a single pulse of sound rather than a continuous wave, but the pulse is still just a pressure wave. In fact you can produce this type of pulse just by letting off an explosive - in this sense an explosion (conventional or otherwise) is a *sonic bomb*.

When a sound wave hits a wall the wall will be subjected to an alternating high then low pressure. If the high pressure is high enough it can push the wall over. This is exactly what happens when an explosion knocks down a wall. There would not be any special optical effects.

If the energy carried by the sound wave is very very high it could in principle heat the wall surface and the layer of heated air could cause some optical effects like a mirage. However since this much energy would just knock the wall down, you'd only have a fraction of a millisecond to see the effect before the wall collapsed.

Comment: nice answer! but can an inner sound of a ship change the wall of a ship cabin( and the wall doesn't collapse)and then the light on the  wall is changed into something else(like an oily sheen)?

Comment: I can't think of any plausible physical mechanism to do that

Comment: @Lincoln - from one of your previous questions I presume you are talking about USS Arizona. Have you looked at Stillwell's book (Stillwell, Paul (1991). Battleship Arizona: An Illustrated History. Annapolis, Maryland: Naval Institute Press.) for the data and survivors' reports?

Comment: just looked at it, but it seems my questions have nothing to do with it , the ship i talk about is a ship in the space, a spaceship, @DeerHunter

Comment: @Lincoln - then the question has no place on Physics.SE. Only realistic effects can be considered here.

Comment: @DeerHunter no physics things in space? why not  tell people   how are things wrong in physics about the sci-fiction?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the link I gave in META. There was a huge sonic boom after a meteor fell in Russia a few months ago.

Here is an article written at the time with another [video included](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2281454/Dramatic-video-captures-moment-sonic-boom-Russian-meteor-terrifies-schoolchildren-smashing-windows-sports-hall.html). It is a karate class going on normaly, the light changes, then the boom breaks the windows. Light precedes boom for obvious reasons.

I suppose if the sonic bomb falls quite close, light change and sonic boom will be concurrent since the eye and ear will not be able to gauge the difference of velocities of sound and light. Also the impact will be larger.

Comment: it seems you mean the light  precedes boom for obvious reasons. no , i dont mean that at all, at that text, it's a low rumble made a cabin distorted, and then the light of the walls of the cabin changed into oily sheen.

Comment: When an earthquake, thirty years ago, hit the sea lake I have my holiday cottage in a neighbor  was there. It was a moonless hour, the quake made a rumble before the shake  arrived  and she said: the whole lake shook with waves and was phosphorescent from the plankton ( it was February). I suppose the walls of a boat would have reflected that.

Comment: yeah, it seems the walls would have reflected that , but im not sure yet .... thank you. by the way , this is your experience ? ... or a text quoting from a book? your experience , i think...

Comment: It is the experience of a friend at the time of the earthquake 80km out of  athens greece in 1981 or so

Comment: "a rumble before the shake arrived "--- yeah, it's almost like the case i talked about---- a low rumble as an inner sound from the ship (like the rumble from the earth inside), distorted the walls sightly, and the lights on the walls change into oily sheen, right? by the way, as in my question---"Can a sound like a sonic boom change an object like a wall? ", can i just ask like this?---"Can a sound like a low rumble  change an object like a wall? " will this be a question about sci-fiction?... @anna

Comment: when a quake comes walls vibrate, if wooden, it is like being in a ship. If brick they may crack or break.During the quake I was in athens on the third floor of an apartment building. I heard the rumble and immediately started rocking and knew it was a quake and not an explosion.

Comment: i dont have enough rep to chat.